# how to zoomIN and zoomOUT my map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

```
    i am fresher in iOS and i am trying to zoomIN and zoomOUT of my map
```

On button click here is my code.

```
centerCoordinate.latitude=21.204894;
centerCoordinate.longitude=72.84084;

MKCoordinateRegion region =MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (centerCoordinate, miles_IN, miles_IN);
[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
```

where `miles_IN` variable become plus on every button click event and its working fine.

but now my problem is when i scrolled my map and change the location and then i press zoom button then it will show my fixed location whereas i want to zoom current location where i scrolled and stop the map view.

In short how can i zoom my map view at any place where i scrolled and stop same like default pinch zooming native behavior, i do not want zoom my fixed location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapView delegate method to get the current region of your mapView as like below,

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self updateWith:mapView.region];
}
```